# Adding Autoscroll to a JavaScript slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel, jquery-slider

I have a simple problem I can't seem to figure out. I have a JavaScript slider in a site I'm [working on](http://www.jackedpack.com/). You need to manually click to the next image in this slider. I want to make the slider scroll through the images automatically. Here is the code, below that is what I've tried:

```
//Carousel interaction
(function() {
    if (document.getElementById('carousel-nav')) {
        var slides = document.getElementById('carousel-images'),
            slidesItems = slides.getElementsByTagName('li'),
            nav = document.getElementById('carousel-nav'),
            navItems = nav.getElementsByTagName('li'),
            current = 0;

        function showSlide(i) {
            if (i != current && slidesItems[i]) {
                slide = slidesItems[i];
                slide.className += ' show';
                setTimeout (function() {
                    slide.className = slide.className.replace('show', 'appear');                    
                }, 1);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    slidesItems[current].className = slidesItems[current].className.replace('current', '');
                    slide.className = slide.className.replace('appear', 'current');
                    current = i;
                }, 300);
                navItems[i+1].className += ' current';
                navItems[current+1].className = navItems[current+1].className.replace('current', '');
                if (i == 0) {
                    if (navItems[0].className.indexOf('disabled') == -1) {
                        navItems[0].className += ' disabled';
                    }
                } else {
                    navItems[0].className = navItems[0].className.replace(' disabled', '');
                }
                var l = navItems.length - 1;
                if (i == slidesItems.length - 1) {
                    if (navItems[l].className.indexOf('disabled') == -1) {
                        navItems[l].className += ' disabled';
                    }
                } else {
                    navItems[l].className = navItems[l].className.replace(' disabled', '');
                }
            }
        }   

        nav.onclick = function(e) {
            e = e || window.event; e = e.target || e.srcElement;
            e = getParentByTagName(e, 'A');
            if (e) {
                var action = e.getAttribute('data-action');
                if (action == 'prev') {
                    showSlide(current - 1);
                } else if (action == 'next') {
                    showSlide(current + 1);
                } else {
                    showSlide(parseInt(action));
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
})();
```

I've tried adding `setInterval(current+1, 10000);` to the bottom block of code:

```
nav.onclick = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event; e = e.target || e.srcElement;
        e = getParentByTagName(e, 'A');
        if (e) {
            var action = e.getAttribute('data-action');
            if (action == 'prev') {
                showSlide(current - 1);
            } else if (action == 'next') {
                showSlide(current + 1);
            } else {
                showSlide(parseInt(action));
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    setInterval(current+1, 10000);
}
})();
```

I'm really new to JavaScript, and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'd really appreciate any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a value to setInterval, you have to pass a function to execute. Try this:

```
setInterval('showSlide(current + 1);', 10000);
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the help Andrea. I tried putting your code in the same place as my code, and it still didn't work. I originally thought that because function showSlide was above, that setInterval would work, but I realize that didn't make any sense for a number of reasons. Is there something I need to delete in the above if statement, or should I put the code in a different order?

Comment: Actually I suggest you to put the setInterval out of the         `nav.onclick = function(e)`, after it and before the close of the `if (document.getElementById('carousel-nav'))`

Comment: Let me know if I understand correctly. I moved 'setInterval('showSlide(current + 1);', 10000);' down two lines to read like this: '} setInterval('showSlide(current + 1);', 1000); })();' Is there a better way I can collaborate on this?

Comment: Correct, that way the setInterval will be the last command before the close of the IF statement. It should work :-)

Comment: hmmm. It's still not working. I'll have to get some help in person. I'll update my answer when I figure out why it isn't working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The other answer was close, and really helped me figure this out. The only problem was the syntax was a bit off.

```
setInterval(function() {
            showSlide(current + 1)
        },5000);
```

The above is what eventually worked for me. So this is how it looked in the above code:

```
nav.onclick = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event; e = e.target || e.srcElement;
        e = getParentByTagName(e, 'A');
        if (e) {
            var action = e.getAttribute('data-action');
            if (action == 'prev') {
                showSlide(current - 1);
            } else if (action == 'next') {
                showSlide(current + 1);
            } else {
                showSlide(parseInt(action));
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
    setInterval(function() { showSlide(current + 1) }, 5000);
})();
```

The next step is to figure out how to have the slider repeat back to the first slide once it reaches the last slide.

Thanks again to Andrea for the help!